# Python .sum adding random numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below `python` code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('MOA_Assignment.xlsx')
PD = pd.DataFrame(wb['Purchase Exit Survey Data'].values)
#drop unneeded rows and columns
PD=PD.iloc[6:,1:]
#sum columns into the 58th row
PD[58]=PD.sum()
```

[image]

Why would `DataFrame.sum()` add strange numbers?
I have used `DataFrame.astype('int')` to make sure the data frame is not an object but it still gives me weird results. The correct results should be `6, 1, 2, 1 ,15` in that order. CNBC alone should have at least more than a result of 3.0 as the five numbers showing add up to more than 3. Please help, thank you.

PD.head().to_dict()

```
{1: {6: 'aapka_colors',
  7: 'baby_first',
  8: 'bloomberg',
  9: 'cbs_sports',
  10: 'cnbc'},
 2: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 3: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: 1, 10: 1},
 4: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 1},
 5: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 6: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 7: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 8: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 2},
 9: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 10: {6: 1, 7: None, 8: 1, 9: None, 10: None},
 11: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 12: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 13: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 14: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 15: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 16: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 17: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 18: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 19: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 20: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 21: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 22: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 23: {6: None, 7: 1, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 24: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 25: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 1},
 26: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 27: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 28: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 29: {6: 1, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 1},
 30: {6: 1, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 31: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 1},
 32: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 33: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 34: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 35: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 36: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 1},
 37: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 38: {6: None, 7: None, 8: 1, 9: None, 10: 1},
 39: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 40: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 41: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 42: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 43: {6: 1, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 1},
 44: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 45: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 46: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 47: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 48: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 49: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 1},
 50: {6: 2, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 51: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 52: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 53: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 54: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 55: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None},
 56: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 1},
 57: {6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: 3},
 58: {6: 7, 7: 7, 8: 7, 9: 1, 10: 3}}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the output of your summation? Also, paste `df.head().to_dict()` so we can work with data. It's not possible to copy & paste images into an interpreter. Finally, please read / study [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
PD[58]=PD.sum()
```

to

```
PD[58]=PD.sum(1)
# P[58] = PD.sum(axis=1) Or this either option does the same
```

you are currently summing columns, you want to sum rows

Comment: They sum to zero now when I run axis=1. I appreciate your response!

Comment: After using .fillna the columns now sum thank you sir!

Comment: @MatthewChung, you are welcome! If My answer appropriate solves your issue, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the hollow check mark, right below the down vote arrow

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your issue.

From the dictionary you have pasted, I see results as expected:

```
res = df.sum(axis=1).to_dict()

# {6: 13.0, 7: 8.0, 8: 9.0, 9: 2.0, 10: 18.0}

df = df.fillna(0.0).loc[:, df.sum(axis=0) != 0]

#               1    3    4    8    10   23   25   29   30   31   36   38   43  \
# 6   aapka_colors  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0   
# 7     baby_first  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
# 8      bloomberg  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0   
# 9     cbs_sports  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
# 10          cnbc  1.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   

#      49   50   56   57  58  
# 6   0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0   7  
# 7   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   7  
# 8   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   7  
# 9   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   1  
# 10  1.0  0.0  1.0  3.0   3
```